# Interpolate from a point on a sphere to a point on a another sphere?

Tags: interpolation, spheres

I am at the moment trying to come up with an solution which is capable of interpolating between a point on a sphere **A** to a point on a sphere **b**.

The interpolation should both provide me with minimal rotational and positional displacement.

What i know is the radius of both sphere, the position A and B relative to the center of the sphere..

Could someone help me come up with a scheme that solves this?

[image]

Comment: I supposed there are more criteria (other than the two points A and B) for the path to satisfy. Otherwise, the path interpolating two points with minimum rotation would be a straight line.